# Set selected state through XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a drawable selector with `android:state_selected` condition. And I want to set this condition through `XML`. But I can't find this state in XML, only through `button.isSelected`.

**How to set this state through XML**?

Comment: post some code?

Comment: Can you please specify your actual requirements

Answer (score 0):

Create Selector XML file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon_checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon_checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon_uncheck" />
</selector>
```

In `android:state_checked="true"` and `android:state_pressed="true"` set drawable which is used for selected button.

In `android:state_pressed="false"` set drawable which is used for unselected button.

I hope its work for you.

Comment: that's not what he asked